# How to select an html element that has two class names?

Tags: html, css, frontend

IE7 doesn't support  :last-child pseudo selector.  I am thinking of explicitly  adding  a class name to denote it as the last element but not sure how to select this element inside a css file.  Anyone  have any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
.class1.class2 {color:red}
```

and

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

or install [IE7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and :last-child will "just work".

Comment: Note that IE6 is broken when it comes to multiple class selectors like this. http://www.ryanbrill.com/archives/multiple-classes-in-ie/ explains in more detail and has a work around.

Comment: the IE7-js library is also a work-around, and it enables first/last-child as well. I love it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
<div class="element"/>
<div class="element last"/>
```

You can just do

```
div.element
{
   // styles effect both divs
}

div.last
{
    // style will only effect the second element and overides because lower in the css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One extra thing to note about multiple classnames is that IE6 can not handle them properly. It will only consider the last classname in the list:

```
.class1.class2 {color:red} => .class2 in IE6
```